# Fetch JSON data and display as variable in a function

Tags: javascript, json

I have tried to get the btc_to_usd value via bitpay api via json url [There is actually what I want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KczKG.png)

**This is the working script requiring manual input of 6277.51 (btc to usd value) and 2636554.2 (btc to naira value)**

```
<script >

    //var btc_to_usd =;
    //var btc_to_ngn = ;
    //var usd_to_ngn = ;
    var btc = document.getElementById("btc");
    var usd = document.getElementById("usd");
    var ngn = document.getElementById("ngn");

    function changeBtc() {
        // usdValue = (btc.value * btc_to_usd);
        // ngnValue = (btc.value * btc_to_ngn);
        usd.value = correctionDecimalsbtc(btc.value * 6277.51);
        ngn.value = correctionDecimalsbtc(btc.value * 2636554.2);
    }

    function changeUsd() {
        btc.value = correctionDecimalsbtc(usd.value / 6277.51);
        ngn.value = correctionDecimalsbtc(usd.value * 420);
    }

    function changeNgn() {
        btc.value = correctionDecimalsbtc(ngn.value / 2636554.2);
        usd.value = correctionDecimalsbtc(ngn.value / 420);
    }

    function correctionDecimalsbtc(value) {
        if(countDecimals(value) > 8) return value.toFixed(8);
        return value;
    }

    function countDecimals(value) {
        if(Math.floor(value) === value) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            if (undefined !== value.toString().split(".")[1]) {
                return value.toString().split(".")[1].length;
            } else {
                return 10;
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

**This is the non-working script that I am trying to get the btc_usd value via json url**

```
<script >

    //var btc_to_usd = $url='https://bitpay.com/api/rates';
$json=json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ) );
$naira=$btc=0;
    //var btc_to_ngn = (btc_to_usd * 420);
    //var usd_to_ngn = ;
    var btc = document.getElementById("btc");
    var usd = document.getElementById("usd");
    var ngn = document.getElementById("ngn");

    function changeBtc() {
        // usdValue = (btc.value * btc_to_usd);
        // ngnValue = (btc.value * btc_to_ngn);
        usd.value = correctionDecimalsbtc(btc.value * 6277.51);
        ngn.value = correctionDecimalsbtc(btc.value * 2636554.2);
    }

    function changeUsd() {
        btc.value = correctionDecimalsbtc(usd.value / 6277.51);
        ngn.value = correctionDecimalsbtc(usd.value * 420);
    }

    function changeNgn() {
        btc.value = correctionDecimalsbtc(ngn.value / 2636554.2);
        usd.value = correctionDecimalsbtc(ngn.value / 420);
    }

    function correctionDecimalsbtc(value) {
        if(countDecimals(value) > 8) return value.toFixed(8);
        return value;
    }

    function countDecimals(value) {
        if(Math.floor(value) === value) {
            return 0;
        } else {
            if (undefined !== value.toString().split(".")[1]) {
                return value.toString().split(".")[1].length;
            } else {
                return 10;
            }
        }
    }

</script>
```

Please help, I have search and went through a lot of solutions and tutorial but no luck.

Comment: what is the error or problem?

Comment: `$json=json_decode( file_get_contents( $url ) );` looks like php in JavaScript??

Comment: If I dont manually input the number in the script, the calculation wont be done.

Comment: Ogbeni, is there any issues using the fetch api? My answer below should do what you want, then you can just set the variables and so on from the response data.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use the [Fetch API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API), like so:

```
var btc = document.getElementById("btc");
var usd = document.getElementById("usd");
var ngn = document.getElementById("ngn");

(async () => {
  let data = await (await fetch("https://bitpay.com/api/rates")).json();
  usd.textContent = data[2].rate
})();

function changeBtc() {
  // usdValue = (btc.value * btc_to_usd);
  // ngnValue = (btc.value * btc_to_ngn);
  usd.value = correctionDecimalsbtc(btc.value * 6277.51);
  ngn.value = correctionDecimalsbtc(btc.value * 2636554.2);
}

// [...]
```

Check this [codesandbox.io/s/runtime-morning-ysxlx](https://codesandbox.io/s/runtime-morning-ysxlx)